# Is the first immigrant of a day always allowed to enter the country?

Tags: papers-please

I've noticed after the first few days into a game that every first immigrant of a day has valid papers and can be approved too enter the country.

Does the game always give you an immigrant with valid papers as the first person to pass by your booth on any given day?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**, the first immigrant is not always allowed to enter the country.

I encountered an immigrant with a forged stamp on her entry permit and she was detained.

[image: Picture of the forged entry permit encounter]

Comment: Was this the day that the forged stamps were introduced? -- I believe that is a new rule is introduced on a day, the first immigrant will be used to visualize that rule: allow on new documents, deny on new restrictions.

Comment: @alexanderpas I believe this was day 11, I'm not sure if it was that particular day that the forgery was introduced.

Comment: Just checked, yes, day 11 is the day forgery is introduced.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [timeline](http://papersplease.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline) on the *Papers, Please!* wiki:
the first entrant will always **be allowed** to enter on **days 1, 2, 3, 6, 7<sup>†</sup>, 8, and 28**
the first entrant will always **not be allowed** to enter on **days 5, 11, 14, 18, 19, 24, and 25**

<sup>† On day 7, you still need to verify some information, you cannot just approve them immediately.</sup>

In general *(except for just day 21?)*, when a new feature is introduced, the first person at the booth gives the player an example of that feature.